# Odoo auto-reloads configuration continously

Tags: odoo-8

I was seeing a strange behaviour, my logs reads thus, and it is continuous:

2016-11-06 19:10:54,667 12342 INFO ? openerp: OpenERP version 8.0

2016-11-06 19:10:54,667 12342 INFO ? openerp: addons paths: ['']

2016-11-06 19:10:54,669 12342 INFO ? openerp: database hostname: localhost

2016-11-06 19:10:54,669 12342 INFO ? openerp: database port: 5432

2016-11-06 19:10:54,669 12342 INFO ? openerp: database user: swampb

2016-11-06 19:10:55,332 12347 INFO ? openerp: OpenERP version 8.0

2016-11-06 19:10:55,332 12347 INFO ? openerp: addons paths: ['']

2016-11-06 19:10:55,333 12347 INFO ? openerp: database hostname: localhost

2016-11-06 19:10:55,333 12347 INFO ? openerp: database port: 5432

2016-11-06 19:10:55,333 12347 INFO ? openerp: database user: swampb

2016-11-06 19:10:55,981 12352 INFO ? openerp: OpenERP version 8.0

2016-11-06 19:10:55,981 12352 INFO ? openerp: addons paths: ['']

2016-11-06 19:10:55,981 12352 INFO ? openerp: database hostname: localhost

2016-11-06 19:10:55,981 12352 INFO ? openerp: database port: 5432

2016-11-06 19:10:55,981 12352 INFO ? openerp: database user: swampb

I was thinking, that it might be due to  something reloading the config file, or calling the main function continuously. I'm unable to debug and find the issue, any help here would be appreciated.

Note: 
I have added and removed databases.

Regards,
Vignesh